# JPA one to one mapping creates multiple query when child entity is not found

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, one-to-one

I have a parent entity 'contracts' that has a one-to-one relation with another entity 'child-contract'. the interesting thing is that the mapping field ('contract_number')id not a primary key-foreign key but is rather a unique field in both the tables. Also it is possible for a contracts to not have any child contract altogether. With this configuration I have observed hibernate to generate 1 additional query every time a contracts does not have a child-contract. I filed this behavior very strange. Is there a way to stop these unnecessary query generation or have I got something wrong.

below is a piece of my code configuration.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "contracts")
public class Contracts implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

  @JsonProperty("contract_number")
  @Column(name = "contract_number")
  private String contractNumber;


    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JsonProperty("crm_contracts")
    @JoinColumn(name = "contract_number", referencedColumnName = "contract_number")
    private ChildContract childContract ;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "child_contract")
@BatchSize(size=1000)
public class ChildContract implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @JsonProperty("id")
  @Column(name = "id")
  private String id;

  @JsonProperty("contract_number")
  @Column(name = "contract_number")
  private String contractNumber;

}
```

Please help.

Thank-you

Comment: Please show the hibernate quesries you were talking about

Comment: its a simple JPQL query with out any join fetch

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NamedEntityGraph` to solve multiple query problem.

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.Contracts.CRMContracts", attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "crmContract") })
```

Use this on your repository method as

```
 @EntityGraph(value = "graph.Contracts.CRMContracts", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
// Your repo method in repository
```